# How can I work on a bzr/hg repository with XCode 4?

Tags: git, mercurial, xcode4, bazaar

I have a Cocoa project managed in a bzr repository, and so far I used bzr just from the command line. But now that XCode 4 natively supports git, I wonder if there's a way to work on it using the nice GUI feature of XCode 4. Any idea is greatly appreciated.

How about the case of a mercurial repository?

Comment: I too use bzr from the command-line and would like to know this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would try [bzr-git](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/migration/en/foreign/bzr-on-git-projects.html) and [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.com/) if you want to use the Xcode 4 GUI.

Comment: While this recommendation is better than none, it doesn't solve the problem. I'm not sure about the original poster, but we want the opposite, in that we want to use BZR as our VCS tool and repository, but use git (Xcode4) as the client. We honestly wanted to like git. It may be great for large open-source projects (i.e. linux kernel), but falls short of BZR in terms of flexibility, especially for smaller dev teams that incorporate artists and programmers, and even more so for Mac/iOS projects. Actually somewhat surprised Apple continues to ignore it.

Comment: Isn't hg-git supposed to be a two-way bridge? Maybe bzr-git is also a two-way bridge? If so, why the downvotes and why such a comment? Upvoting since -1 looks very ugly here.

Comment: I am new to this website so I just gained the ability to comment. They are two way bridges, so you should be able to use your bzr repositories normally. Also, I know a bit more then most about version control in Xcode 4, and I would say that they are probably looking at version control popularity and they are aware that these bridges exist. In short, it may be a while before your favorite version control shows up in xcode, if it comes at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.com/) for the Mercurial repository.

After installing hg-git, I performed `hg gexport` to convert the repository to a git repo, side by side. This is not enough for Xcode 4.0.0 (maybe newer releases fixed this): apparently it does not, at least, tolerate "bare" repositories (those not cloned from other ones, from what I gathered), as well as other properties of hg-git repos.

To solve this I only had to clone the git repository using `git clone MyProject MyProjectGIT`. Then I opened the `MyProject.xcodeproj` in folder `MyProjectGIT`, worked on it, committed using Xcode 4, and pushed back to the original git repository (the one side-by-side with the Mercurial repository). For that I used command line: `git push`. I could have probably used Xcode 4 GUI, but, meh. Finally, I imported the changes back into the Mercurial repository using `hg gimport` and pushed them onto the remote BitBucket repository using `hg push`.

Note that you probably don't have username and email configured with git by default, so the committer will be messed up.

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email your.email@example.com
```

Possibly more detailed instructions (or just different) are [available on my blog](http://blog.vucica.net/2011/05/using-hggit-with-existing-mercurial-projects.html).

Regarding Bazaar repositories, I'm afraid I cannot help there. I have not used Bazaar yet, and unfortunately I do not see a need to use it for any serious work in the nearby future; Mercurial fulfills my needs, and my greatest need for even git comes only from people publishing software in git repositories, and from Xcode 4 [not yet](http://openradar.appspot.com/8098649) supporting Mercurial. I hope you'll find what you need for Bazaar as well!